# How to set the click on Down button effect on beamer?

Tags: beamer

How to make the effect of "When I click on Down button on beamer, another sentence appears" ? Do I need to set multiple frames? If yes, how to make all of these frames on the same page ?

How to proceed please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use the *overlay specifications* that [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) supplies. This includes things like `\only`, `\onslide`, `\pause`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you have to use itemize or enumerate.

A code could be:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> stuff that appears immediatly
  \item<2-> stuff that appears only when you press the down arrow on you keyboard
  \item<3-> stuff that appears when you press a second time and so on...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: You could add the simpler `\begin{itemize}[<+->]\item stuff... \end{itemize}`.